# C++ gcc Namespace not found

Tags: c++, gcc

I know there are many similar topics but there are equally many unique mistakes that may lead to this problem (so I think). Therefore I ask, after some research.

My problem is that the compiler, GNU GCC, when compiling one file does not see my namespace declared in another file. The IDE (CodeBlocks) evidently does see it as it auto-completes the name of the namespace. I tried to isolate the problem and came up with this:

File main.cpp:

```
namespace MyName
{
    int MyVar;
}

#include "T1.cpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

File T1.cpp:

```
using namespace MyName;
```

*error: 'MyName' is not a name-space name.*

In my project I have a header file, say T1.h, and an implementation file T1.cpp — and MyName isn't accessible in either of them.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Including a *.cpp file is generally a bad idea.  What do you expect to happen when "T1.cpp" is compiled on its own?

Comment: why would you `#include "T1.cpp"` from main.cpp? Rename it to .h then

Comment: When you compile "T1.cpp" it is not being included in "main.cpp" therefore it isn't preceded by the `namespace` declaration. The `namespace` should be a in a header included by both implementation files, and you should not include implementations in each-other.

Comment: @Pavel: it has nothing to do with the extension. In any case, MyName isn't accessible from the .cpp associated with the .h file.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This makes sense, thank you. If I may ask, are the contents of one implementation ever pasted by compiler (or preprocessor) into another implementation, the "master" implementation (or whatever one should call it)?

Comment: @vpprof and what file is "associated with the .h file"? If T1.cpp has only single line as you said it cannot be compiled on it's own

Comment: @there is no such thing as "contents of one implementation ever pasted by compiler (or preprocessor) into another implementation". #include means you take that file that you want to include and put its contents in place of that include directive.

Comment: @vpprof No, this never happens unless you `#include` them yourself (which you should generally not do). Each implementation file is compiled by itself without any regard for any other implementation file's compilation. Each results in it's own intermediate file. These files are then linker together in a separate step.

Comment: @vpprof with C++ each `.cpp` file is compiled independently. Usually header files will have some kind of declaration like `class MyClass`, which tells the compiler that `MyClass` exists somewhere, and don't worry about it until later. The linker will find all the missing parts of each `.cpp` file and combine them.

Comment: Hey guys, a very big "thank you" for your valuable information; I think I have a good chance now of finally understanding the idea of .h and .cpp files. So basically each .cpp spawns an .o or .obj file and then the linker combines them into .exe?
And my _Main.cpp_ does not need to know the workings of any classes that might be declared in .h files — it just needs to know they exist and what arguments they take — and that is why I must include the .h files in my _Main.cpp_? Is that right?

Comment: @vpprof that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that CodeBlocks is compiling both main.cpp and T1.cpp. Here is what happens when you try to compile each one:

main.cpp:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
$
```

T1.cpp

```
$ g++ T1.cpp
T1.cpp:1:17: error: ‘MyName’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace MyName;
                 ^
T1.cpp:1:23: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace MyName;
                       ^
$
```

T1.cpp, when compiled on it's own, has no knowledge of `MyName`. To fix this, don't include `.cpp` files, and put your declarations in header files.

Edit: From what I gather, this may be a better way to organize your example:

T1.h:

```
namespace MyName {
    extern int MyVar;
}
```

T1.cpp

```
#include "T1.h"

int MyName::MyVar = 5;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "T1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace MyName;

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyVar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now it will compile correctly:

```
$ g++ -c T1.cpp -o T1.o
$ g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
$ g++ T1.o main.o
$ ./a.out
5
```

Comment: I see. But the problem persists when I include a header, say _T1.h_ in _Main.cpp_ — the MyName namespace is invisible to _T1.h_. So I understand that including a header file _T1.h_ in _Main.cpp_ does not in any way make the code in _Main.cpp_ visible to the associated implementation file _T1.cpp_?

Comment: @vpprof as I said, imagine that includes were replaced with contents of the files. What you would get in this case is what compiler sees and for that reason you get errors. It seems that you do not understand this simplest concept.

Comment: @vpprof take a look at my edit and let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @Pavel, yes, I daresay I understand how the preprocessor works, thank you. The piece of information that I was missing, is that every .cpp compiles on its own with no regard to any other .cpp. Now I understand, my _main.cpp_ compiled correctly while my _T1.cpp_ compiled incorrectly because it had no knowledge of the _main.cpp_'s existence.

Comment: @Alden — yes indeed, this makes sense. One question though, is the `extern` absolutely necessary? Would the compiler show errors if it encountered two definitions like `int MyVar`? Does this logic also apply to declaring functions?

Comment: @vpprof `extern` tells the compiler to not allocate space for the variable because it will be allocated elsewhere. If excluded, with `T1.cpp` it will complain that `MyVar` is being redefined. Functions behave differently. You can declare a function, `int myfunc();` and define a function, `int myfunc() {return 1;}`. Declarations should go in headers and they let your `.cpp` know that the definition will exist somewhere.